# Graphing $\frac{x^2-x+1}{2(x-1)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

I need to graph

$$\frac{x^2-x+1}{2(x-1)}$$

So I reduced it to make the derivative easy:

$$f(x) = \frac{x(x-1)+1}{2(x-1)} = \frac{x}{2} + \frac{1}{2(x-1)}\\f'(x) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2(x-1)^2}$$

which has roots $x = 0, x = 2$

But the derivative of the [original](http://bit.ly/12YEHo1) function and the one [I made](http://bit.ly/1BMM6D2) are different. I can't see why. The two have the same roots, but I can't see what i'm doing wrong.

The concavity was easy to find by the derivative I made, but i don't know what's happening

Comment: What makes you think $\dfrac 1 2 - \dfrac 1 {2(x-1)^2}$ is different from $\dfrac{(x-2)x}{2(x-1)^2}\text{ ?}$  They are the same. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : Look again!

Comment: @Cameron: Somehow I read $1-x$ instead of $x-1$.

Comment: @Brian: Been there!

Comment: @MichaelHardy sorry, I though the second wolpram query was graphing the derivative, but is the original function, so i though they were different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are, in fact, the same expression. Your solution gives:

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2 \left ( x - 1  \right)^2 }$$

And the other one gives:

$$f'(x) = \frac{x\left(x - 2 \right)}{2(x - 1)^2}$$

First, one could notice the common denominator of $2(x - 1)^2$ seen in both expressions. This should stick out to you. Try rewriting the derivative on the top into a single fraction, and then compare the two results.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, but they *aren't* different! They're just written differently. Try combining your derivative's terms over their least common denominator, then factor the numerator by noting that it is a difference of squares. You should get the same thing as Wolfram's derivative of $f(x).$

Comment: I though they were different because I saw the graph of the second one, and it was graphing the original function, not the derivative. By the way, how would you analyze its signal?

Comment: What do you mean by "signal"?

Comment: positive or negative

Comment: Aha! I would call that the "sign," rather than the "signal," but now I think I understand. So, if $f'(x_0)>0,$ what does that say about the behavior of $f$ at $x_0$? What about if $f'(x_0)<0$? (If the answer is "I don't know," then that's fine, but think about it, first. This will come up a lot.)

Comment: If I think of it as the compact derivative of the first link, then it's only a case of analyzing the signal of the numerator, since the denominator is always positive. But it isn't clear how is the sign of the function in my derivative

Comment: One can simply factor out $\frac12$ to get $$f'(x)=\frac12\left(1-\frac1{(x-1)^2}\right).$$ Readily, $\frac1{(x-1)^2}$ is always positive, and $\frac12$ is positive, so the only thing left to do is determine for which $x$ we have $1>\frac1{(x-1)^2},$ for which $x$ we have $1<\frac1{(x-1)^2},$ for which $x$ we have $1=\frac1{(x-1)^2},$ and for which $x$ $\frac1{(x-1)^2}$ is undefined. Does that make things clearer for you?

Comment: Ultimately, though, the more compact form is better. As a rule, if you have a sum or difference of rational functions, it is a good idea to combine them over a common denominator (keeping in mind the domain restrictions), just in case it allows a simpler, more compact form.

Answer (score 1):

Find the common denominator of your denominator:  $$\frac 12 - \frac 1{2(x-1)^2} = \dfrac{(x-1)^2 - 1}{2(x-1)^2} = \frac{x^2 - 2x}{2(x-1)^2} = \frac{(x-2)x}{2(x-1)^2}$$

Note that the derivative is zero when the numerator (not the denominator) is zero. In terms of graphing the function, the solution(s) to $f'(x) = 0$ will yield the values of $x$ where extrema exist (equilibrium points where the function is neither increasing nor decreasing.)

$$x(x-2) = 0\iff x=0\;\;\text{or}\;\; x = 2$$

Test each solution value to determine which is a maximum, which a minimum. That will help you in graphing the function.